# Win7 C++ - Issue starting executable as user from service logged in as user

Tags: c++, service, impersonation

I am fixing an issue with a windows service that has up to this point had no problems impersonating the current user and starting an executable in that user's session.

My original issue was that I couldn't access information about mounted drives or the files on them.  So I found I needed to define the service to log in as the user.

Once I did that I no longer had problems accessing these files, but impersonation for starting the executable no longer works. Or more specifically, my call to `WTSQueryUserToken()` no longer works, but returns false, and `GetLastError()` returns ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD.

I don't yet know if I will run into any issues with `DuplicateTokenEx()` or `CreateProcessAsUserA()`, but one thing at a time.

My code is as follows (dwSessId was retrieved before this point and is correct):

```
if (dwSessId >= 0)
{
    HANDLE hCurrentToken;
    HANDLE hPrimaryToken;
    BOOL ok = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessId, &hCurrentToken);
    if (ok)
    {
        ok = DuplicateTokenEx(hCurrentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hPrimaryToken);
        // now we start the executable process as the current user
        STARTUPINFOA si;
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
        ret = (CreateProcessAsUserA(hPrimaryToken, procname.c_str(), NULL, 0, 0, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &m_pProcInfo) != 0);
    }
}
else
{
    int err = GetLastError();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) documentation:

> To call this function successfully, the calling application **must be running within the context of the `LocalSystem` account** and have the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege.

In other words, you can't configure your service to run as any particular user.  But, it can certainly *impersonate* a user when needed, as long as the thread that is calling `WTSQueryUserToken()` is not impersonating a user at the time of the call.